# Funcionameto Iterator

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida absurda com uso de Iterator, estou fazendo um exercicio em que eu tenho uma classe Data que verifica a existencia da data, essa está funcionando perfeitamente,no meu principal eu faço um array de data e dou setData em algumas

```
Data d[] = { new Data(), new Data(), new Data(), new Data() };

    d[0].setData( 2, 4, 2016 );
    d[1].setData( 12, 3, 2006 );
    d[2].setData( 3, 3, 2006 );
    d[3].setData( 7, 9, 2015 );
```

Até ai tudo bem, a duvida me surge quando vou usar um for each para imprimir todas as datas entre uma duas

```
for( Data x : new RangeData( d[2], d[1] ) )
        System.out.println( x );
```

Na classe RangeData eu crio um iterator, mas como ele funciona? Ja li na documentação que o hasnext retorna true se houver um proximo elemento no iterator e o next retorna o próximo elemento, mas como eu preencho o iterator com essas datas ? Minha construção do iterator está correta ? O que falta? Como posso Melhorar?

```
@Override
public Iterator<Data> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Data>() {
        Data hoje = data;


        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return hoje.equals(data2);
        }

        @Override
        public Data next() {
            return hoje;
        }

    };
}
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: O `RangeData` iria passar em cada dia entre as duas datas escolhidas ? A sua classe `Data` está implementada à mão ou baseia-se na implementação de `Date` e derivados ?

Comment: Exatamente isso, a RangeData vai passar por cada dia entre as duas, e minha classe data está implementada à mão mesmo, ela simplismente testa se a data existe levando em consideração ano bissexto, quantidade de dias de cada mês e essas coisas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Na classe RangeData eu crio um iterator, mas como ele funciona?

A sua explicação é exatamente o que faz:

> Ja li na documentação que o hasnext retorna true se houver um proximo elemento no iterator e o next retorna o próximo elemento

Ou seja `hasNext` tem de avaliar se já esta na data final e o `next` tem de devolver e avançar no dia. É importante tambem perceber como isto encaixa com um `foreach` normal. Olhando por exemplo para:

```
for (Data x : new RangeData(d[2], d[1]))
```

Internamente o Java vai obter o iterador retornado por `RangeData` e chamar `next()` para obter o valor para `x` em todas as iterações do `for`. E apenas termina o `for` quando o `hasNext()` desse mesmo iterador retornar `false`.

> mas como eu preencho o iterator com essas datas ?

Vai precisar de guardar a data inicial e final recebidas no construtor dentro da classe `RangedData` e utiliza-las no iterador criado dentro dela. O iterador será responsável por avançar dia a dia e devolver o dia apropriado.

Exemplo:

```
public class RangeData implements Iterable<Data>{
    private Data inicio;
    private Data fim;

    public RangeData(Data inicio, Data fim) {
        this.inicio = inicio;
        this.fim = fim;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Data> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<>() {
            //data corrente do iterador começa como a data de inicio da RangeData
            Data corrente = inicio; 

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                //se já chegou ao fim ou não. Tem próximo se a data corrente
                //for menor ou igual à data de fim
                return corrente.menorOuIgual(fim); 
            }

            @Override
            public Data next() {
                Data atual = corrente; //data a devolver, a atual
                corrente = corrente.proximoDia(); //corrente avança 1 dia
                return atual;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Agora falta implementar os métodos `menorOuIgual` e `proximoDia` utilizados no iterador que exemplifiquei acima. Por simplicidade e até porque o foco da pergunta não é esse, considere a seguinte implementação (`proximoDia` não está correto mas serve para exemplificar):

```
public class Data {
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int ano;

    public Data(){ //para que o código que tinha não deixe de funcionar
    }

    public Data(int dia, int mes, int ano){
        setData(dia, mes, ano);
    }

    public void setData(int dia, int mes, int ano){
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public boolean menorOuIgual(Data data) {
        return ano < data.ano || 
              (ano == data.ano && mes < data.mes) ||
              (ano == data.ano && mes == data.mes && dia <= data.dia);
    }

    public Data proximoDia(){
        //não está correto, mas exemplifica para as duas datas da pergunta
        return new Data(dia + 1, mes, ano);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { //para que o System.out que tem no main funcione
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%d",dia, mes, ano);
    }
}
```

Com isto o seu `main` já irá funcionar.

Saida:

```
03/03/2006
04/03/2006
05/03/2006
06/03/2006
07/03/2006
08/03/2006
09/03/2006
10/03/2006
11/03/2006
12/03/2006
```

[Veja a execução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/MOTVFL)

Como pequeno aparte, aconselho a simplificar a construção das datas no `main`, utilizando um construtor (aquele que eu exemplifiquei) que receba os valores que pretende diretamente ao invés de ter que fazer `setData` para cada data individualmente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, explicou de forma excelente, agora só vê se eu entendi , o iterator cria internamete uma lista do tipo definido ( sabendo préviamente quem é o ultimo) e vai acrescendo ela até que chegue no último e o hasNext seja falso. Correto?

Comment: @PatrickSasso O iterador não tem que criar uma lista. No exemplo da resposta não é criada uma lista, apenas anda de data em data até chegar à data limite (`hasNext` dá falso). Cada data anterior não é memorizada em lado nenhum e por isso é descartada. O avanço das datas é feito com um método da sua classe `Data`. Um iterador mais comum, tipo o de `ArrayList` ou `LinkedList` será de facto suportado por uma lista na sua implementação. O que talvez ainda não seja claro é que o `foreach` vai chamar `next()` e utilizar o elemento que sai dele até que o `hasNext` dê falso.

Comment: Perfeito! Entendi o funcionamento e sanou minhas dúvidas.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o padrão iterator serve para você encapsular a iteração em um conjunto de objetos, para que tu não tenha que saber se o objeto é um ArrayList, uma HashTable ou uma árvore, se implementar o iterator você pode realizar um foreach.

No teu caso realmente precisa dessa RangeData? Ela está bastante equivocada e se  o problema é apenas iterar em um subarray você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira

```
int[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(d, 1, 3);
Iterable<Data> iterable = Arrays.asList(subarray);
for( Data x : iterable ) ){
   System.out.println( x );
}
```

Estamos criando um subarray a partir do seu array principal, transformando o seu array em uma lista (Listas implementam a interface Iterable em java) e fazendo um foreach em cima desse cara.

Sobre a tua implementação, acho que você está um pouco perdido e não vale a pena eu replicar o que já existe em ótima qualidade por ai, segue um post sobre o tema, talvez um dos melhores em português: 
https://www.devmedia.com.br/padrao-de-projeto-iterator-em-java/26733